# DAX - Histogram for relative frequencies and total column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I built a diagram that displays the relative frequencies of my clusters (on the values in the column) and the cumulated frequencies (on the values on the line).
My chart has this aspect:
[image]

I would like to add a new column to the right that is equal to the sum of all the values of the previous columns.
The relative frequencies are created using the code below:

```
"Frequencies UL" :=
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'table1'[Column1] );
    USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Order Cluster'[Cluster Name]; table1[tag Cluster] );
    SUMMARIZE ( table1; table1[tag Cluster] )
)
```

I would really appreciate some help!

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a [Cumulative Total](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/) pattern.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I I had already seen the article, but how I can create a column with the sum of the previous columns?

Comment: What do you have on the x-axis? That's what you use in the cumulative total unless it's categorical, in which case you need to use an index that gives the order you want.

Comment: Yes on the x-axis I have a categorical class and I have order it with an index. In the sixth class I indicated "total" but I can not create a relationship with the clusters and total

Comment: I have already built the measure for the cumulated sum in this way: 

`Cumulative Freq UL = CALCULATE(SUM('tab1Freq'[Frequencies UL]);USERELATIONSHIP( 'Order Cluster'[Cluster Name]; table1[tag Cluster] );FILTER(ALLSELECTED('tab1Freq'); 'tab1Freq'[Order Cluster] <= MAX('tab1Freq'[Order Cluster])))`

Comment: Doesnt seem an optimal visualisation design.  As shown in Alexis' mockup below you'll compress the detail of the actual histogram charts, with the only useful extra info being the tiny data label. A separate Card visual would probably be better, showing just `DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'table1'[Column1] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply it was necessary to do this:

```
"Frequencies UL" := IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Order Cluster'[Is Total]);
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT ('table1'[Column1]); ALL('Order Cluster')); DISTINCTCOUNT('table1'[Column1]))
```

And this is the result I got!

[image]

Comment: Wait, you already had a total row in your `'Order Cluster'` table? That would have been hugely useful information to provide in the question since that's really the hardest part of making this work. With that in place, the question is completely different and much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest creating a new table to use for your x-axis.

If your `'Order Cluster'` table looks like this:

```
ClusterName  Order
ClusterA     1
ClusterB     2
...          ...
ClusterZ     26
```

You want to add a `Total` row to the end so try something along these lines:

```
NewTable = UNION('Order Cluster', {("Total", MAX('Order Cluster'[Order]) + 1)})
```

Use `NewTable[ClusterName]` for your chart's x-axis and tweak your cumulative measure to reference `NewTable[Order]` in the `FILTER` inequality.

You'll also need to adjust your frequency measure to handle the case when you have the `Total` cluster (use an `IF` or `SWITCH`) and make sure you're evaluating within the correct filter context. Something like this logic:

```
IF( MAX( NewTable[ClusterName] ) = "Total",
    CALCULATE( [Frequency Calc], ALLSELECTED( table1 ) ),
    CALCULATE( [Frequency Calc],
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED( table1 ),
            table1[tag Cluster] = MAX( NewTable[Order] )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Line Bar Chart]

P.S. You might be better off adding the total row to your `'Order Cluster'` table in the query editor instead of having another table floating around. In any case, the logic is similar; add a total row to the column you're using for your axis and adjust your measures to handle that category how you want.

---

A waterfall chart might be another option to consider (and doesn't need nearly as much work), though I don't know that you can include the percent info except in the tooltip.

[image: Waterfall Chart]